# I want to subtract elements from 2 nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested, subtraction

I have these two nested list:

```
insurance cost = [('Maria', 4150.0), ('Rohan', 5320.0), ('Valentina', 35210.0)]
estimated insurance cost = [('Maria', 4222.0), ('Rohan', 5442.0), ('Valentina', 36368.0)]
```

I want to make a code to subtract estimated by insurance so complete a subtraction on every 2nd element in the list. how would i do that?.
Do I unzip or convert back to int(). I've just started learning python and was wondering how to do it. Anyone know how to go about this.

Comment: Ok... You cannot have spaces in variables

Answer (score 1):

You can go with:

```
total_cost=[(i[0],j[1]-i[1]) for i,j in zip(insurance_cost, estimated_insurance_cost)]
print(total_cost)
```

Also, variables in python don't have **spaces** between them. `python` will consider words as new variables, which won't be defined and would be syntactically invalid.

You can use `_` as an alternative:

```
insurance_cost = [('Maria', 4150.0), ('Rohan', 5320.0), ('Valentina', 35210.0)]
estimated_insurance_cost = [('Maria', 4222.0), ('Rohan', 5442.0), ('Valentina', 36368.0)]
```